# How to tell pytest-xdist to run tests from one folder sequencially and the rest in parallel?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-xdist

Imagine that I have `test/unit/...` which are safe to run in parallel and `test/functional/...` which cannot be run in parallel yet.

Is there an easy way to convince pytest to run the `functional` ones sequentially? Consider that we are talking about a big number of tests so altering each test function/method would be very noisy.

At this moment we run tests with marker filters so mainly we run them separated. Still, I am looking for a solution for removing the need to run them separated.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement your own scheduler that acts like `load` or `loadscope`, depending on what module the test is defined in. Example:

```
from xdist.scheduler.loadscope import LoadScopeScheduling


class MyScheduler(LoadScopeScheduling):
    def _split_scope(self, nodeid):
        if 'test/functional' in nodeid:
            return 'functional-tests'
        return nodeid


def pytest_xdist_make_scheduler(config, log):
    return MyScheduler(config, log)
```

All tests under `test/functional` will be grouped under the same node `functional-tests` (and thus run in the same worker), the rest will be run in parallel as usual.

Comment: I'm getting an unresolved import error on the LoadScopeScheduling import. Do I need to be importing this in a certain location / is this possible to do when relying on pip or do I need to fork xdist?

Comment: @Rustang most probably you haven't install the package correctly. Try running `python -c "import xdist"` first to verify the package is importable at all from your current environment.

Comment: Hmm interesting, `python -c "import xdist"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xdist`, regardless of pytest-xdist definitely being in my pip list. OK well that's a start - thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rustang the next guess would be that the `pip` command points to the wrong executable. List installed packages via `python -m pip list`, install via `python -m pip install` etc to match.

Comment: This scheduler code goes in a `conftest.py` file in the main test directory, for anyone else who's confused about how to get pytest to use this scheduler. Quite a helpful and extensible answer!