# Could I condition pytest-xdist parallel execution with test dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, pytest, hierarchy, pytest-xdist

I was finding out some kind of combination of *pytest-xdist* with dependency-related plugins like *pytest-dependency* (but it seems to have some incompatibilities, better to say, [they don't get along](https://github.com/RKrahl/pytest-dependency/issues/8)), or  *pytest-ordering* with the same [problems](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/issues/36#issuecomment-279822189).

What I need is to **run in parallel but injecting some constraints** to guarantee that some tests related to common tasks (mainly database provision for specific tests) are executed isolated prior the rest of tests of a 'parallelization' group. For example, I would like to organize my tests something like this:

```
test_suite1 / test_provision.py
            / chapter1 / test_a.py
                         test_b.py
                         ...
            / chapter2 / test_provision.py <= don't pay attention on test names issues (this
                         test_a.py            can be named  test_suite1_chapter2_provision.py
                         test_b.py            or __init__.py can be used to avoid the problem
                         test_c.py            of unique names)
                         ...
              ...
test_suite2 / test_suite2_provision.py
              ...
...
```

The idea is to run parallelization respecting the constraints related to dependencies, so, for example, when entering the globbed list of collected tests for `test_suite1`, pytest-xdist should stop at `test_provision.py` running it serially, then run chapters in parallel and so on. Some chapters could have also constraints (i.e. chapter2 test_provision.py) and this shall be also respected: first provision, then chapter2 child tests ...
In the example `chapter2 / test_provision.py` is in the same directory as tests, this is not a matter of filesystem hierarchy organization (although this is probably a project agreement and probably should be uniform: for example, provision tests isolated on parent directories or something like this). Thus, I expect to insert pytest marks or similar to create dependencies at tests definitions, not at filesystem.

If this idea is difficult to carry out, perhaps a simplification could be **mark a test to be executed uniquely when reached** (*stopping pytest-xdist* parallel execution for the whole bunch of collected tests), then, although others could indeed be parallelized with it we could sacrify this for a greater good which is avoid collisions in the test plan (and thus, avoid failed executions).
But this would imply greater total execution time and **I would prefer to avoid this solution**.

Also, I don't want to run every provision test at the beginning (like `pytest -m 'provisions' ; pytest -m 'others'`) because some provisions are specializations of upper ones and are incompatible with other branches provision brothers. So, from *pytest-xdist* point of view, every test, when *reached* shall acts as it is designed to do.

EDIT: my concern could be understood as a requirement to establish some kind of test affinity towards an specific *pytest-xdist* worker. This is because If i ensure that some directories are managed by a single worker, I could control the whole picture.

Comment: You would need to write your own scheduler; check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/59498774/2650249 for an example.

Comment: Ok, thank u for the link. I understand that in that example, MyScheduler groups those under `test/functional/` to be the same module, and, as that inherits from loadscope this means they run in the same worker: sequentially. But in my case, I think I would need them parallel, but depending on some upper tests in the file hierarchy.So, that group and the group with provisions (normally 1 provision test), are sequential themselves, but parallel within them. Could a user-defined scheduler reach that objective ?